# How to invoke javascript functions in a WebView in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am new in Universal app development. Can any one help me into following code,

I have load one website using web view control in universal app. I want to read some control value from same website.

My label control id is 'lblDestination' on website.

I am accessing this in universal app like 
`MAinPage.xaml`

```xml
<WebView x:Name="Browser"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 Loaded="Browser_Loaded"
                 NavigationFailed="Browser_NavigationFailed">
</WebView>
```

`MAinPage.xaml.cs`

```
Browser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('lblDestination')" }).ToString()
```

Is this right way to read the browser control value?
I am using the simulator for testing this app, So is simulator creating the problem?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure where and when you use [`InvokeScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx) with the JavaScript `eval` function to inject content into the web page. But usually we can use [`WebView.DOMContentLoaded` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.domcontentloaded.aspx). This event occurs when the **WebView** has finished parsing the current HTML content so with this event we can make sure the HTML content is prepared.

And If we want to invoke JavaScript inside the **WebView** content in Windows 10 Universal app, we'd better use [`WebView.InvokeScriptAsync` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) as

> [**InvokeScript** may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use [InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx).]

Last but not least, please do note that the `InvokeScriptAsync` method can only return the string result of the script invocation.

> The invoked script can return only string values.

So if the return value of your JavaScript is not a string, the return value of `WebView.InvokeScriptAsync` method will be a empty string.

If you use

```
var value = await Browser.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('lblDestination')" });
```

the value will be a empty string as `document.getElementById('lblDestination')` returns an `Element`.

So to read some control value, you can try using code like following:

```
var innerText = await Browser.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('lblDestination').innerText" });
```

And if the value you want to get is not a string, you may need to convert it to string in JavaScript first. For example:

```
var childElementCount = await Browser.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('lblDestination').childElementCount.toString()" });
```

Comment: Thanks for Quick replyJay

Comment: I got solution on this   I have wrote the async method wrong             previous-   private async  void GetResponseCallbackDest(IAsyncResult result)  {