# How to invoke javascript in WebView Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to load a javascript in WebView to do some calculations and get the output in a string. I tried to use following code

```
string htmlFragment = "<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>" +
                    "function doubleIt(incoming){ " +
                    "  var intIncoming = parseInt(incoming, 10);" +
                    "  var doubled = intIncoming * 2;" +
                    "  document.body.style.fontSize= doubled.toString() + 'px';" +
                    "  return doubled.toString());" +
                    "};" +
                    "</script></head><body>" +
                    "<div id = 'myDiv'>I AM CONTENT</div></body></html>";
            htmlView.NavigateToString(htmlFragment);
            htmlView.LoadCompleted += async(s1,e1) =>
              {
                  string result = await htmlView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "doubleIt(25)" });
                  Debug.WriteLine(result);
              };
```

**Update**
I am able to load simple javascript easily now based on help provided in the answer. But now I am facing issues when there is more than one function in javascript, I am getting an exception. I am trying the following code

```
string htmlFragment = @"<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>" +
                    "function a(){return 10;};" +
                    "function b(){return 20;};" +
                    "function c(){return 30;};" +
                    "return (a()*b()*c());" +
                    "</script></head><body>" +
                    "<div id = 'myDiv'>I AM CONTENT</div></body></html>";
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke javascript functions in a WebView in Universal Windows App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286761/how-to-invoke-javascript-functions-in-a-webview-in-universal-windows-app)

Comment: @Kinani I used same but not sure why it is giving value empty.

Comment: You need to get rid of the window.external.notify and actually do a return of your value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for this feature is really poor. It took me some time to figure out how to invoke `Javascript` in UWP `WebView`

When you first look at the function call `webView.InvokeScriptAsync(string,string[])` your initial reaction is that they want the function name as the first parameter and then the function paramaeters as the string array. [(mainly because the MSDN documentation says this)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx)

> **Parameters**
>
> **scriptName**
>
> Type: System.String [.NET] | Platform::String [C++]
>
> The name of the script function to invoke.
>
> **arguments**
>
> Type: System.String[]
>   [.NET] | Platform::Array [C++]
>
> A string array that
>   packages arguments to the script function.

HOWEVER, this is wrong and will lead to hours of head banging. REALLY, what they want is the word "eval" in the first parameter and then a string array of functions, and or commands you wish to eval

```
   var value = await webViewer.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", 
      new string[] 
      { 
        "functionName(functionParams)" 
      });
```

Having worked with Microsoft APIs for a few years now I am convinced that this is not the intended way of consuming this function and is a bit of a hack. Unfortunately if you want to consume JavaScript this is the only way that I know that works currently.

Comment: I tried based on your suggestion but still getting the value as empty. I have updated my code in `LoadCompleted` event. Can you please suggest?

Comment: Get rid of the window.notify and actually do a return of your value

Comment: thanks now it is working. Can you suggest why due to window.notify, it was  causing issue?

Comment: This entire WebViewer control is so janky I have no idea why it's not working. Sorry

Comment: Can you check `Update` for this question?

Comment: What is the exception?  Where is your invocation?

Answer (score 1):

Anthony,
Try to check your own suggestion:

```
 await webViewer.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", 
  new string[] 
  { 
    "functionName(functionParams)" 
  });
```

or:

```
await webViewer.InvokeScriptAsync(functionName, new string[]{ functionParameters });
```

The same as Microsoft suggests, just you are limiting a function name by one ("eval") - not necessary. Trust me, you can use any function name, as I am now with UWP and before with windows phone hybrid apps.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already 4 years old, but I'm coming to see why you were getting an empty string as a result.

In your example, the functions in JavaScript return integers while the expected value is of type string.

By modifying these functions and returning a string like this:

```
string htmlFragment = @"<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>" +
                    "function a(){return '10';};" +
                    "function b(){return '20';};" +
                    "function c(){return '30';};" +
                    "</script></head><body>" +
                    "<div id = 'myDiv'>I AM CONTENT</div></body></html>";
```

We get the good result on the way back.