# c# call javascript function written in hosting application from webview control in client application

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, asp.net-mvc-5, uwp

I have a UWP app using Webview control. The source for the webview is a url for a asp.net web application running on localhost. The url has javascript functions written in it. My question is how can i call javascript function written in web application from the uwp webview control.

```
<Page
x:Class="signalRonRPi3.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:signalRonRPi3"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="callJS" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,298,0" Click="callJS_Click" >Call JS</Button>
    <WebView x:Name="webViewUrl" Source="http://localhost:52527/Home/Image" Height="500" Width="500" Margin="50" />
</StackPanel>
```

How do i call a javascript function written in the source url from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly. You want to invoke the Javascript within the source url. In that case you can use [InvokeScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx) method.

You can refer this question on StackOverflow [How to invoke javascript functions in a WebView in Universal Windows App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286761/how-to-invoke-javascript-functions-in-a-webview-in-universal-windows-app) to get more details.